# Printing Out Prime Numbers in C

Tags: c, for-loop, numbers, cs50

I'm attempting to print out the prime numbers up to a certain value that is obtained from the user. I imagine there is something wrong with my for loop if I only ever receive an answer of 1?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("Length: ");
    int length = GetInt();

    bool notPrime = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k <= i/2; k++)
        {
            if (i % k == 0)
            {
                notPrime = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            { 
                notPrime = false;
            }   
        }
        if (notPrime == false)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This should not be too hard to pen-and-paper-debug for at least the first couple of values. Did you try that? What did that tell you?

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the internal loop:

```
for (int k = 1; k <= i/2; k++)
```

You are starting with `k = 1` and testing if `k` divides `i`. `1` divides any integer, so the answer will always be "non prime", which is not the case (remember the definition of *prime number*). Start from `2`:

```
for (int k = 2; k <= i/2; k++)
```

Answer (score 3):

in the internal loop:

```
for(k=2; k<=sqrt(i); k++)
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to check the special cases and you can start from 3.
Also you can increment by 2 exluding the pair numbers:

```
for(int i = 1; i < length; i++){

    if(number < 2) prime = true; 
    if(number == 2) prime = false;
    if(number % 2 == 0) prime = false; 
    for (int k = 3; k <= i/2; k++){
        if(number % i == 0 ){ 
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (prime){
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```

You should make the IF's out of the first bucle, and also you can change k <= i/2 -> sqrt(i)